# How to assign a numerical code to a string based on a set of keywords in R

Tags: r, string, multidimensional-array, text

For example, I have an array of data in which some text descriptions are given as follows:

1. big Pool House
2. 1 storey Warehouse
3. multiple Storage pool

Now, I want to code the text descriptions based on the sub-strings. For example, if there is string "pool" in a text, then I want to assign a numerical code (say, 101) to the whole text description.

If there are multiple strings in a text description (say, "storage" and "pool"), then I want to assign multiple codes to those descriptions and concatenate/paste the codes. For example, in case of the description - "multiple Storage pool" , I would assign the code (say, 102) to storage and 101 to pool. So, the result should be (102, 101).

Could anyone please suggest an R algorithm for this?

Comment: In the `keras` package for R there is a `text_tokenizer` function which can then be fit to a body of text to produce numerical representations of some tokens (typically words). You can then use `texts_to_sequences` to produce the numerical sequences you mention. See here for an example: https://jjallaire.github.io/deep-learning-with-r-notebooks/notebooks/6.1-one-hot-encoding-of-words-or-characters.nb.html

Comment: [Soundex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex)? See, for instance, `?stringdist::stringdist`. But this is greatly opinion-based, a reason to vote to close. (Which I haven't, at least not yet) can you show what you have tried?

Comment: @Valeri Voev, @ Rui Barradas -- Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data

```
data <- c("Big Pool House", "1 Store Warehouse", "Multiple Storage Pool")
```

First define the keywords to search in the data and the corresponding codes

```
tags <- c("Storage", "Pool", "Warehouse")
ids <- c(102, 101, 103)
```

Then use

```
lapply(data, function(x) ids[which(sapply(tags, function(y) grepl(y, x)))])
[[1]]
[1] 101

[[2]]
[1] 103

[[3]]
[1] 102 101
```

---

**Edit 1** considering the comment of @Valeri Voev about the argument `ignore.case` in `grepl`.

By default the function grepl is case-sensitive. If in the data, sometimes you have a keyword in lowercase and sometimes in uppercase, use the argument `ignore.case` with value `TRUE` so that the function ignores the case.

For instance if the data has the word "pool" in both, lower and uppercase formats

```
data <- c("Big Pool House", "1 Store Warehouse", "Multiple Storage pool")
```

use

```
lapply(data, function(x) {
  ids[which(sapply(tags, function(y) grepl(y, x, ignore.case = TRUE)))]
})
```

If you leave `ignore.case = FALSE` (default), `grepl` will not detect that "pool" is in the last element and the code 101 will not be assigned to it.

---

**Edit 2** to complement the answer with two extra requirements of the OP not stated in the question but in a comment.

- To have the codes separated by commas, you can use the function `paste` with `collapse = ','`.
- To make it a data frame, better use `sapply` rather than `lapply` so that you get the output as a vector of characters instead of as a list.

All together would be

```
codes <- unname(sapply(data, function(x) {
  paste(ids[which(sapply(tags, function(y) grepl(y, x)))], collapse = ",")
}))
data.frame(Data = data, Codes = codes)
                   Data   Codes
1        Big Pool House     101
2     1 Store Warehouse     103
3 Multiple Storage Pool 102,101
```

Comment: `grepl` has a `ignore.case` parameter that can be set to `TRUE` to override case-sensitive-ness.

Comment: Ok...the output is just as i desired. Is it possible to Concatenate/paste the numbers by a Comma (",") seperated value and make it a dataframe.

Comment: Check out Edit 2.